# Is there a way to save "char * argv[]" to a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, clang++

I'd like to be able to save argv into a struct so that it can be passed to functions like so:

```
struct Parameters {
    int argc;
    char * argv[];
};

void Start(
    Parameters P
) {

};

int main (
    int argc,
    char * argv []
) {
    Parameters P;
    P.argc = argc;
    P.argv = & argv;


    return 0;
}
```

But with:

```
clang++ -std=c++2a -stdlib=libc++ -rtlib=compiler-rt -Ofast Start.cpp -o Start && ./Start;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Start.cpp:21:9: error: array type 'char *[]' is not assignable
```

Is there a way of saving argv to a variable?  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's of type `char**`, so just assign that to something else that's the same type. You're calling it as `char***` with the `&argv` reference.

Comment: As a note, this multi-line function signature style is really unconventional and makes following this code unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: In C++ you can also initialize the structure with the properties already populated, that's more efficient than initializing then populating.

Comment: in the struct it should be `char **argv;` , and in main , `P.argv = argv;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change to:

```
struct Parameters  
{
    int argc;
    char ** argv;
};
```

Your `argv` array of pointers to `char` will decay to a pointer to pointer to `char`.

Then, your main becomes simpler, with:

```
P.argv = argv;
```

Comment: Thanks @"Jeffrey supports Monica"!

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to convert it to a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of strings:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Note: use argv + 1 to skip the application name in args.
    //       If you want to include the application name then don't use
    //       the +1
    std::vector<std::string>    args(argv + 1, argv + argc);

    // Now this can be passed to functions easily.
    // args.size()  == number of arguments.
    // args[x] == the string for argument x

}
```

Comment: Wow, never thought about this.

Comment: yeah, but you then incur the cost of copying memory

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica Yah point to be noted. But I feel that `vector<string>` is more easier to work with than `char* []`. Obviously, there is a trade off.

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica: Sure but it simple to change `std::string` to `std::string_view<char>` if you don't want to incur that cost.